# How to go to previous cell and make this code faster?

Tags: excel, vba

When running code that deletes an EntireRow, going to next cell will not delete the next cell based on the same parameters because that cell gets moved down into the current slot.

IE:

```
for each cell in r
if cell.value = "A" then cell.entirerow.delete
next cell
```

The above code will delete A1 if A1="A" but if A2 also = "A" it will not be deleted because when it goes to next cell A2 it was moved to A1.  When it's now looking at A2, that is the cell that was A3, so at best it looks at every other cell.

To get around this i do stuff like this:

```
DoItAgain:
For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = "A" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo DoItAgain
    End If
next cell
```

This works well but when running this code on 100k lines, it takes way too long.  I'm thinking that's because my `DoItAgain` method brings it all the way back to the first cell and that's a lot of cells to loop through if there's 100k or more cells to look at.

This is the entire code I'm using right now.  It was working very well until I started receiving a lot more data and then it's taking too long for it to be useful:

```
Private Sub Ford_Inventory_Variance_File_CleanUp()
Call ScreenOff

If IsEmpty(Range("A2")) Then Range("A2").EntireRow.Delete
If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete

LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

DoItAgain2:
Set r = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A20:A" & LastRow)
For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = "**** End Of Report ****" Then GoTo ItsTrimmed
    cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo DoItAgain2
    End If
Next cell

ItsTrimmed:
DoItAgain:
For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = "**** End Of Report ****" Then Exit Sub
    If InStr(1, (cell.Value), "/") = 0 And InStr(1, (cell.Value), "Total of Inventory") = 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo DoItAgain
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(Left(cell.Value, 1)) And InStr(1, (cell.Value), "Total of Inventory") = 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo DoItAgain
    End If
Next cell

Call ScreenOn
End Sub
```

Screenupdating is off, but this code takes forever.  instead of `Next cell` can I use `Previous cell`?  Is previous cell a thing?  Maybe I could use `previous cell` instead of `GoTo DoItAgain`?

Any input on how to speed this up will be greatly appreciated.  I write codes like this a lot using my `GoTo DoItAgain` method, i probably have 100 macro's like this, but I might need a better way.  My boss is entrusting me with more work but I need to speed this process up.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would help you if I would understand what **exactly** is to be done. I do not understand why you need "**** End Of Report ****", since you iterate up to the `LastRow`.. So, the rows to be deleted are the the empty ones, the ones not containing "/" and "Total of Inventory", not being number and not containing "Total of Inventory". Are these conditions enough, please?

Comment: Those conditions are enough.  The "End Of Report" is because the last row is moved down as rows are deleted as the code runs so the actual "LastRow" will be shorter by the time it reaches the end of the document.  I need something better than my "DoItAgain" method I think.  I'm not a professional coder however.  Just self taught VBA a bit.

Comment: I will post an answer in some minutes. It should be very fast, making a Union range of the rows to be deleted, and delete them at once, at the end of the code... If above conditions are enough, I will prepare it fast enough, I think...

Comment: Also, my code with "DoItAgain" will go through an infinite loop deleting empty cells at the end of a document without something like "End of Report"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It is untested, but it should work. It, basically, works on the next mechanism: It iterates between all cells of the defined range and check each of them against the set conditions. If a condition is `True`, it marks the cell like necessary to be deleted (making the boolean variable `True`). After that, in case of `boolToDelete = True`, the respective cell it is added to the `rngDel` (range to be deleted). Finally, using`rngDel`, all the rows are deleted at once (very fast):

```
Private Sub Ford_Inventory_Variance_File_CleanUp()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, rngDel As Range, boolToDelete As Boolean
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 20 To lastRow
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
        boolToDelete = True
    ElseIf InStr(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, "/") = 0 And InStr(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, "Total of Inventory") = 0 Then
        boolToDelete = True
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(left(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, 1)) And InStr(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, "Total of Inventory") = 0 Then
        boolToDelete = True
    End If
    If boolToDelete Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then 'for first time (when rngDel is nothing)
            Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i)
        Else 'next times a union of existing rngDel and the processed cell is created
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i))
        End If
    End If
    boolToDelete = False 'reinitialize the boolean variable
  Next i
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp 'rng deletion at once
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully!  Thank you so much!  Looking at your code I can basically understand what it did, but I will have study the code and booleans in general when I have time so that I can understand how to write similar codes. Amazing!

Comment: @Glad I could help!. I will edit the code and comment the line which (I think) are not so easy to be understood...

Comment: i see the highlights and comments you added.  again, very helpful.  thank you,

Answer (score 0):

FaneDuru gets 100% credit for answering my question.

I'm posting the full modified code I'm using however:

```
Private Sub Ford_Inventory_Variance_File_CleanUp()

Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, rngDel As Range, boolToDelete As Boolean

If IsEmpty(Range("A2")) Then Range("A2").EntireRow.Delete
If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete

lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set r = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:N" & lastRow)
For Each cell In r
    cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
Next cell

  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 20 To lastRow
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
        boolToDelete = True
    ElseIf InStr(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, "/") = 0 And InStr(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, "Total of Inventory") = 0 And sh.Range("A" & i).Value <> "**** End Of Report ****" Then
        boolToDelete = True
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(Left(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, 1)) And InStr(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, "Total of Inventory") = 0 And sh.Range("A" & i).Value <> "**** End Of Report ****" Then
        boolToDelete = True
    End If
    If boolToDelete Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i))
        End If
    End If
    boolToDelete = False
  Next i
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp

End Sub
```

Everything Dane wrote is fast.  The longest part of my code is now the trim function I wrote where it trims all the cells in ("A1:N" & LastRow).